# How to center panel with controlled aspect ratio

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, aspect-ratio

In wxPython, I'm having trouble centering a sub-panel that I've created to have a fixed aspect ratio.

To control the aspect ratio, the sub-panel needs to capture the Size event and then do an explicit SetSize.  So, I've done that and it works well.  Unfortunately, when I embed this sub-panel into another panel (using a sizer), the wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL flag doesn't work.

Apparently, the sizer tells my sub-panel that it has the whole width to fit within.  When my window doesn't use the whole width, then the sizer doesn't adjust.  Here is a simplified version of my code that shows the problem:

```
import wx

ROWS = 6
COLS = 25

class TestPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)

        label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Label')
        grid  = TestGrid(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(label, 0, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(grid,  1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class TestGrid(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE,  self.OnSize)

    def OnSize(self, event):
        w, h = self.GetSizeTuple()
        delta = min(w // COLS, h // ROWS)
        self.SetSize((COLS*delta, ROWS*delta))
        self.Refresh()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "Test", size=(600, 200))
    panel = TestPanel(frame)
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

This is a screen capture:
[image: Demonstration of problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As VZ explained in his answer, your `wxEVT_SIZE` handler isn't a very good idea. Remove it. When using sizers, you have to work within the sizer infrastructure to achieve what you want.

You want your `TestGrid` to fill as much space as possible within its parent, while maintaining a certain aspect ratio; that's exactly what `wx.SHAPED` is for (combined with a `proportion` greater than 0, which you already have). So, you should add `grid` to the sizer like this:

```
sizer.Add(grid,  1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.SHAPED)
```

The only other thing you need to do is tell the sizer what your desired aspect ratio is. The easiest way is to set an initial size for your `TestGrid` (before it's added to the sizer); for example, set the size of its `wxPanel` base:

```
wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1, size=(COLS*7, ROWS*7))
```

That's all there is to it.

(I'm just guessing the Python syntax, so ignore any obvious errors :-) )

Answer (score 0):

You can't, or at the very least shouldn't, resize a window from its own `wxEVT_SIZE` handler. I'm not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve, but if the goal is to encapsulate everything in `TestGrid` class, then you should let it have whichever size it has and create a nested window in it that you would resize to the appropriate size in your `OnSize`.